# How can I prevent the JavaScript Prompt Leaving site From Appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am trying my best to figure it out how to remove the Javascript prompt/confirm that says "Do you want to leave this site?" like this:

https://prnt.sc/famast

Basically what's happening here is that when a modal got opened and the user click on "YES" it will redirect to a page. But I don't want the JavaScript confirmation but just redirect it to that page.

Any idea if you know some scripts that could make it happen?

Please help!

Comment: Search your codebase for a `prompt()` in an `onbeforeunload` event handler, then you can just remove it

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: provide your javascript codes ..

Comment: onbeforeunload is [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) so, read the docs

Comment: Search for 'window.onbeforeunload' and remove that section. Thats the code which is showing the alert.

Comment: Or better, do a non-whole-word search for `beforeunload`. That way you can find the code even if it doesn't explicitly reference `window`, or if it uses `addEventListener` to add the `beforeunload` listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other said above me, you can do it with `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return '';
    // The browser shows a pre-defined message so you don't have to write your own
}
```

You can also use `addEventListener`, in this way:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    return '';
});
```

[See an example](http://jsbin.com/coquzuqume/1/edit?html,js,output) (Link updated)

Comment: @GaaraItachiUchiha I'm glad I could help :-) have fun!